# Azure DevOps API release definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm getting the following error when trying to copy a release template from a different project

> "VS402982: A retention policy is not set for the stage ‘PROJECT-ENV’. Retention policies at the release pipeline level are deprecated.

```
{
    "id":  8,
     "name":  "PROJECT-ENV",
     "rank":  1,
     "owner":  "@{displayName=Zoe MacKay;  _links=; id=; uniqueName=Zoe.MacKay;imageUrl=https://dev.azure.com/incrementalgroup/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/}",
     "variables":  "",
     "variableGroups":  "",
     "preDeployApprovals":  "@{approvals=System.Object[]; approvalOptions=}",
     "deployStep":  "@{id=27}",
     "postDeployApprovals":  "@{approvals=System.Object[]; approvalOptions=}",
     "deployPhases":  "",
     "environmentOptions":  "@{emailNotificationType=OnlyOnFailure; emailRecipients=release.environment.owner;release.creator; skipArtifactsDownload=False; timeoutInMinutes=0; enableAccessToken=False; publishDeploymentStatus=True; badgeEnabled=False; autoLinkWorkItems=False; pullRequestDeploymentEnabled=False}",
     "demands":  "",
     "conditions":  "",
     "executionPolicy":  "@{concurrencyCount=1; queueDepthCount=0}",
     "schedules":  "",
     "currentRelease":  "@{id=70; url=https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/; _links=}",
     "retentionPolicy":  "@{daysToKeep=30; releasesToKeep=3; retainBuild=True}",
     "processParameters":  "",
     "properties":  "",
     "preDeploymentGates":  "@{id=0; gatesOptions=; gates=System.Object[]}",
     "postDeploymentGates":  "@{id=0; approvals:[]; gatesOptions=; gates=System.Object[]}",
     "environmentTriggers":  ""
 },
```

copying from current build.

Answer (score 7):

Your JSON is not valid. You'll need to ensure all the nested values are expanded correctly. For example:

```
"retentionPolicy":  "@{daysToKeep=30; releasesToKeep=3; retainBuild=True}",
```

should be

```
"retentionPolicy": {
          "daysToKeep" : 30, 
          "releasesToKeep": 3,
          "retainBuild": true
         },
```

If you're using PowerShell to create this JSON then ensure to specify the Depth parameter so it expands each value correctly.