# Azure DevOps API release definition error

Tags: azure-devops

I am creating azure-devops release pipeline with API, but getting error. I have validated the JSON as well and is correct from https://jsonlint.com/ Any help would be really appreciated
I have followed this issue as well and retention policy is correctly passed

[Azure DevOps API release definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360972/azure-devops-api-release-definition)

> error: "message": "VS402982: A retention policy is not set for the stage ‘Test-New-2’. Retention policies at the release pipeline level are deprecated. Use a retention policy at the stage level

```
POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0
```

JSON body:

```json
"retentionPolicy": {
                "daysToKeep": 30,
                "releasesToKeep": 3,
                "retainBuild": true
            },
```

Comment: I think the full JSON might be helpful.  Is the `retentionPolicy` listed in the `environments` array?

Comment: Yes retention was correctly passed, but issues was with the syntax only. which even the the syntax lint check was not able to pick. Correcting the syntax resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be the syntax issue, to create a release definition, you could refer to this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#create-release-definition).

Reruest URL:

```
POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "source": "undefined",
  "revision": 1,
  "description": null,
  "createdBy": null,
  "createdOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "modifiedBy": null,
  "modifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "variables": {},
  "variableGroups": [],
  "environments": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "PROD",
      "variables": {},
      "variableGroups": [],
      "preDeployApprovals": {
        "approvals": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "isAutomated": false,
            "isNotificationOn": false,
            "approver": {
              "displayName": null,
              "id": "aeb95c63-4fac-4948-84ce-711b0a9dda97"
            },
            "id": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      "postDeployApprovals": {
        "approvals": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "isAutomated": true,
            "isNotificationOn": false,
            "id": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      "deployPhases": [
        {
          "deploymentInput": {
            "parallelExecution": {
              "parallelExecutionType": "none"
            },
            "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
            "artifactsDownloadInput": {},
            "queueId": 15,
            "demands": [],
            "enableAccessToken": false,
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
            "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "overrideInputs": {}
          },
          "rank": 1,
          "phaseType": "agentBasedDeployment",
          "name": "Run on agent",
          "workflowTasks": []
        }
      ],
      "environmentOptions": {
        "emailNotificationType": "OnlyOnFailure",
        "emailRecipients": "release.environment.owner;release.creator",
        "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
        "enableAccessToken": false,
        "publishDeploymentStatus": false,
        "badgeEnabled": false,
        "autoLinkWorkItems": false,
        "pullRequestDeploymentEnabled": false
      },
      "demands": [],
      "conditions": [],
      "executionPolicy": {
        "concurrencyCount": 0,
        "queueDepthCount": 0
      },
      "schedules": [],
      "retentionPolicy": {
        "daysToKeep": 30,
        "releasesToKeep": 3,
        "retainBuild": true
      },
      "properties": {},
      "preDeploymentGates": {
        "id": 0,
        "gatesOptions": null,
        "gates": []
      },
      "postDeploymentGates": {
        "id": 0,
        "gatesOptions": null,
        "gates": []
      },
      "environmentTriggers": []
    }
  ],
  "artifacts": [],
  "triggers": [],
  "releaseNameFormat": null,
  "tags": [],
  "properties": {},
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Fabrikam-web",
  "projectReference": null,
  "_links": {}
}
```

I test it on my side, it works for me.

[image]

Comment: What is the ID of the task that we can pass while creating a fresh release job, The release job ID goes 0, but task that is passed in workflowTasks": [] section can't be passed as 0.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error when 'GET' release definition and 'PUT' update back.
Because I didn't set the -depth parameter properly when call ConvertTo-Json.

```
$Release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -ContentType "application/json" -headers
$headers -Method GET
$Release.variables.$varName.value = "$varNewValue"
$json = ConvertTo-Json ($Release) -Depth 7
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json
```